# Find element in vector with property

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a fast search for an object with a particular value in a vector of structs or classes? c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718341/how-to-make-a-fast-search-for-an-object-with-a-particular-value-in-a-vector-of-s)

Is there faster way to find object inside vector with specified value of some parameter than using iterators and stop when I find ? I have vector

where

```
class Simple{
public:
string name;
int id;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any faster way.

Comment: Not unless there is some special ordering of the vector. If it's sorted for example, you can use lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range etc. which will be faster.

Comment: find() template method from STL should do that, although it iterates through all the vector.

Comment: @m0skit0 `find` compares values. This is a job for `find_if` - unless he wants to overload `operator =`.

Answer (score 10):

Without knowing anything about the vector (sorted or not, etc.), the fastest you can get is linear time (much like using iterators).

But you can use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) to beautify the code - although it will still run in linear time.

If you're querying the container multiple times, you might want to sort it (`O(n*log(n))`) and then use a binary search (`O(log(n))`). But this only pays of if the number of queries is comparable to the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

- If You use sorted vector, You could use binary search.
- You can replace `std::vector<Simple>` with `std::map<int, std::string>`.

Comment: The first option only makes sense if you have sufficient queries - sorting is expensive itself. The second suggestion is just plain wrong. His version allows him to have multiple `Simple` objects with the same `int` member but different strings, and vice-versa.

Comment: Read carefully, please. I have not written that somebody should do sorting.

Comment: Unless he does sorting, how can he get a sorted vector?

Comment: You are absolutely right about the second option. I have suggested that it should be unique because identifiers are usually unique.

Comment: For example, he could load vector from database or from file.